# Add a query param using declarativeNetRequest in manifest V3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Getting Started Example",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [
      {
        "id": "ruleset_1",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "rules_1.json"
      }
    ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting",
    "declarativeNetRequest",
    "declarativeNetRequestFeedback"
  ],
  "host_permissions": ["*://example.com/*"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
  },
  "options_page": "options.html"
}
```

rules_1.json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "redirect",
      "redirect": {
        "transform": {
          "queryTransform": {
            "addOrReplaceParams": [{ "key": "test", "value": "123" }]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "condition": {
      "urlFilter": "https://example.com",
      "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
    }
  }
]
```

I am playing around with the example extension code from google, I want to add a query param to an existing url, this work but its clunky because:

1. I have to navigate to the page
2. Click the extension and hit a button
3. Go in the url bar and press enter

Then it adds the query param.

[![url updated][1]][1]

Question:

Is it possible to just add the query param as soon as it hits the url instead of having to do the steps above?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KH6tY.png

Comment: There's no need to click the extension's icon for DNR rules to work, so it may be a bug in Chrome. Anyway, extensions can't modify the contents of the address bar, so substitution happens only when the URL is actually navigated.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm sure I did this a while ago using webRequest but that's playing up in V3 for me, I think it was onBeforeRequest or something. Is there no way to do this using DNR? I am finding a few things more difficult with V3. Thanks.

Comment: And you're right I can access DNR rules without click in the extension, my mistake.

Comment: DNR does the same as webRequest, so I don't understand the difference you see. Maybe a screen recording would help.